# Data binding helper element not working to fetch Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database

The following code should get data from my Firebase database and display it in my Polymer paper-card. But the binding does not seem to work.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-feed">

<template>

<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  paper-card{
    width:100%;
  }.top{
    margin-top: 8px;

  }
</style>

<style is="custom-style">
 .header { @apply(--paper-font-headline); }
</style>

<paper-card>
  <div class="card-content">
      <div class="header">Welcome to Nam Kaalai</div>
      <p>
        Nam Kaalai is an online platform for you to sell and buy native
        breed cattle and their milk products all without the need for you
        to leave your room. However, you should note that this is a platform
        for you to negotiate with the dealers and we do not make arrangements
        for you to get the cattle and their products to your home.
     </p>
  </div>
</paper-card>

<paper-card class="top">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="header">The Market</div>
    <p>
      Thinking of selling your native breed cattle? The members of the Nam Kaalai community are eager to buy your cattle.
      So why wait, sell your cattle to people who want it and help conserve their progeny.
    </p>
    <paper-textarea id="cattleInfo"label="Tell us about your cattle." char-counter maxlength="145">
    </paper-textarea>
    <paper-input id="placeInfo" label="Where do you live with your cattle?">
     <iron-icon icon="communication:location-on" prefix></iron-icon>
    </paper-input>
    <paper-input id="priceInfo" label="Price" always-float-label auto-validate pattern="[0-9,','," "]*" error-message="Only numbers are allowed!">
      <div prefix>Rs. </div>
    </paper-input>
    <paper-input id="contactInfo" label="Contact: Email, phone or social links">
       <iron-icon icon="communication:email" prefix></iron-icon>
    </paper-input>
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <h5>Upload a photo of your cattle (Only one)<h5>
    <!--uplod image-->
    <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileUpload" on-change="upld"/>
  </div>
</paper-card>

<!--Toast to notify of upload-->
<paper-toast id="toast" text="Information about your cattle has been uploaded!"></paper-toast>

<template is="dom-repeat" id="menu" items="{{datas}}">
  <paper-card>
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>{{item.cattleInfo}}</p>
        <p>{{item.placeInfo}}</p>
        <p>{{item.priceInfo}}</p>
        <p>{{item.contactInfo}}</p>
    </div>
  </paper-card>
</template>
```

```
Polymer({

  is: 'my-feed',

  properties: {
      datas: {
        type: Array,
        value: []
      }
  },

  attached: function() {
    var myFeed = this;
    var uploadsRef = firebase.database().ref('cattle/data');

    uploadsRef.on('value', function(snap) {
      var data = _.map(snap.val(), function (item, key) {
        item.key = key;
        return item;
      });
      myFeed.splice.apply(myFeed, ['datas', 0, myFeed.length].concat(data));
    });
  },

  //Gets information and photo and posts them into firebase database &
  //storage.
  upld: function(a) {
      //Get image
     var file = a.target.files[0];

     //create a storage reference
     var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + file.name);

     //store the image
     var task = storageRef.put(file);

     //Upload info to RDB
     var cattleInfo = this.$.cattleInfo.value;
     var placeInfo = this.$.placeInfo.value;
     var priceInfo = this.$.priceInfo.value;
     var contactInfo = this.$.contactInfo.value;

     task.on('state_changed', null, null, function() {
       var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
       firebase.database().ref('cattle/data').push().set({
          cattleInfo: cattleInfo,
          placeInfo: placeInfo,
          priceInfo : priceInfo,
          contactInfo : contactInfo,
          downloadURL: downloadURL
       });

     });


     //show toast that upload is successful
     this.$.toast.open();

     //Clearing the input fields
     this.$.cattleInfo.value = "";
     this.$.placeInfo.value = "";
     this.$.priceInfo.value = "";
     this.$.contactInfo.value = "";

   }

});
```

How do I fetch data from Firebase database and bind it to the paper card element?

Comment: Have you looked at the [firebase-element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element)?

Comment: @Ben I looked at it but I don't know how to implement it. Can you help me?

Comment: @Ben But its for the older version of Firebase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-feed',

  properties: {
    datas: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
    }
  },

  attached: function() {
    var myFeed = this;
    var uploadsRef = firebase.database().ref('cattle/data');

    uploadsRef.on('value', function(snap) {
      var data = _.map(snap.val(), function (item, key) {
        item.key = key;
        return item;
      });
      myFeed.splice.apply(myFeed, ['datas', 0, myFeed.length].concat(data));
    });
  }
});
```

Your template is iterating through `myFeed.datas`, so you need to be attaching the Firebase data to `myFeed.datas` rather than `my-feed.data`. I don't know what `my-feed.data` would do... the dash in the variable name looks like a syntax error.

You'll want to have `datas` be an Array property on your `my-feed` element, and you'll want to use the `myFeed.splice()` function to manage it. I'm doing something a little fancy with the splice and the concat in my example, but it does a great job of splicing out any existing data from the array and replacing it with the fresh data. The `splice()` trick does a great job of keeping the object in sync.

Comment: I have just uploaded my entire html code, pls help me... This is kinda urgent.

Comment: Thanks for the help!